# Serving two different functions withing the same js file in an MVC app (no **Jquery** solution please)

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I am building an **MVC** app which will have two different plans for
users, one of them with restrictions on some functionalities provided
via js. What I need is to serve both plans within the same app but I am
a little confused in how would be the best way to implement it. I have
planned to include both codes within the same js file and comment both,
the restricting function and the un-restricting one and then try to
create a function which allows the users to access their plan on a
fixed condition. I am wondering if it is even
possible to be done and if it is, then someone to bring me a simple
example which I could be able to re-factor and reproduce within my app
environment.

Sorry if I do not provide any code but it would be very complicated to
display here the code of my app. I think I would be done with just a
simple example like this:

> user **A is restricted** and user **B is unrestricted**. The main.js
> file will allow the users to add text lines to the **index.html**
> file. The restriction would be to limit the amount of lines that
> could be added by the user **A**, let's say to 5 lines, while the
> user **B** would be able to add as many lines as he wants. To do
> that, as I imagined and said before, both, the `addLine function` and
> the `restrictedAddLine function` would be commented. Then, if user
> **A** access the app the **main.js file** will be served with the
> `restrictedAddLine function` **uncommented** and the `addLine function` still commented, and viceversa if it is the user **B** the
> one who access the app.

If someone is able to bring such an example, or any link to a similar
question already answered (which I could not be able to fine out there)
it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you're dealing with users, you must have a login system right? And a server side code that will validate the users right? In that case, you retrieve information of your user and depending the plan, you make the app behave diferently.

Comment: Yes, I know that, and I already have it done, I mean the server side user registration system, but I am stucked in how to implement the "you make the app behave differently". I already have the code to restrict the functionalities and it's working fine but what I need is a method to automatically serve one or the other plan without having two build two different apps

Comment: Well, you can save the information of the user plan in a javascript variable or in a hidden html input. And then, from the main.js file, you read the value of the variable or the input, and put the if condition and make it behave differently. What is your tech stack? Backend language? I'll post an example answer in PHP.

Comment: One common approach for tasks that aren't security sensitive is to pass the user role as a variable in page and check that role within functions. Then same code works for multiple roles

Comment: Alexandru Trandafir Catalin, it could be PHP but I would rather preffer js solution as I do not understand PHP at all and I do not want to find someone else to do this for me, but if you have a PHP solution it would be appreciated  too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Posted the answer, btw keep in mind that the order in which you run the code matters, the js variable must be set before loading the main.js script.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by a user can "add text lines"?  2. Are all the js files you mentioned all client side to run in the browser?

Comment: Alexandru Trandafir Catalin, yes, thank you for the claering tip. Now I'm going to try to implement it in my app code. It seems to be very easy indeed but as I do not know well PHP syntax it mayde take a little bit more. Then I will come back and set the answer as accepted. Thks a lot, you saved me lot of hours and dirty search!

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS You don't have to write it in PHP. I mean. I am asking you what is your app's language? If it is php, fine, but if not, no matter the language, the important think to know is to get the user information and expose the "plan" someway so the javascript functions can read it.

Comment: Old Geezer, 1- What I mean with "add text lines" is just an example functionality which could be any thing else, I used it as an example to illustrate the question. 2- Yes, all js files are served on the client side and will run on the browser. The unique part of the app which will run on the server side is the registration/login module

Comment: Alexandru Trandafir Catalin Yes, my main language is js and this **¨expose the "plan" someway so the javascript functions can read it** is precissely where I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you were doing this on a PHP page:

```
<?php
// this is a string containing the plan of current logged user
$user_plan=$database->getCurrentUser()->plan;
?>
<html>
<head>

<script text/javascript>
// set a global js variable with the plan
var userPlan='<?php echo $user_plan; ?>';
</script>
</head>
<body>


<input type="button" value="Add line" onclick="add_line()" />

<script text/javascript>
function add_line() {
  if (userPlan=='basic') {
    alert('You can only add one line');
    return;
  } else {
    // add as many lines
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So the whole point is, to access your user information, make the plan  available somewhere in the HTML. Then read the plan from javascript and behave differently depending on it. Also, no need to maintain multiple functions, just use the same and put the condition of the plan inside.